# Bigger Title in Radarchart plot - R

Tags: r, radar-chart

I'm using `radarchart` from `fmsb` to make a spyder plot.
Anyone knows how to make the title bigger?

Here is the code

```
 data=as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10))
colnames(data)=c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , "R-coding", 
"data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )


data=rbind(rep(20,10) , rep(0,10) , data)
radarchart( data  , axistype=1 , 

            #custom polygon
            pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=1 , 

            #custom the grid
            cglcol="gray48", cglty=1.1, axislabcol="gray48", caxislabels=seq(0,1,5), cglwd=0.9,

            #custom labels
            vlcex=0.8,title=paste("Cluster 1 ")
)
```

**Caveat: i don't want to use `ggradar` package**

Comment: What package does the `radarchart` function come from?

Comment: Sorry.. post edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it the `radarchart` function from the package `fmsb`?
If yes, you should be able to put `cex.main = 3` or something inside `radarchart()`:

```
radarchart( data  , axistype=1 , 

            #custom polygon
            pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=1 , 

            #custom the grid
            cglcol="gray48", cglty=1.1, axislabcol="gray48", caxislabels=seq(0,1,5), cglwd=0.9,

            #custom labels
            vlcex=0.8,title=paste("Cluster 1 "),

            cex.main = 3
)
```

(See `?par`)