# Format RadarChart in R (title, subtitle and labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

Here's the data:

```
df <- data.frame(Jan = 2230, Feb = 2420, Mar = 2833, Apr = 2192, May = 2332, Jun = 2577, Jul = 4363, Aug = 3747, Sep = 3176, Oct = 3988, Nov = 2144, Dec = 1896)
df <- rbind(4363, 0, df)
```

And here's the code to build the radar chart:

```
radarchart(df, 
           pcol = '#B62682', pfcol = alpha("#E1f56E", 0.7), plwd = 2, 
           axistype = 1, cglcol = "lightgrey", cglty = 1, 
           axislabcol = "black", cglwd = 1, caxislabels=seq(0, round(max(df[,1]), 0), round(max(df[,1])/8, 0)),
           calcex = 1, palcex = 1, vlcex = 1, seg = 7,
           title = "Title")
```

[image: radarchart]

Ideally, I want to change the title's font size, add a subtitle and change the order of the labels (month labels should follow a clockwise direction). If this can't be done using `radarchart()`, I'm open to use other libraries. With `ggplot()` it would be super simple using `labs()` to add a title and subtitle and `plot.title`, `plot.subtitle`, etc to format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `radarchart` come from? I also don't understand the logic of adding two rows of all the same value, when it seems like that's not something you're trying to show in the chart

Comment: Hi @camille, ```radarchart``` is a function from a package called ```fmsb```that, as you can see, lets you plot a radar chart. The logic behind adding those two rows is because that is the format that the ```radarchart``` function expects. First row is the max and the second row is the min.

Comment: For the title question, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445974/bigger-title-in-radarchart-plot-r?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Complete answer:

```
radarchart(df, 
           pcol = '#B62682', pfcol = alpha("#E1f56E", 0.7), plwd = 2, 
           axistype = 1, cglcol = "lightgrey", cglty = 1, axislabcol = "black", cglwd = 1, 
           caxislabels=seq(0, round(max(df[,1]), 0), round(max(df[,1])/8, 0)),
           calcex = 1, palcex = 1, vlcex = 1, seg = 7)

mtext(side = 3, line = 2.5, at = 0, cex = 1.75, "Title", font = 2)
mtext(side = 3, line = 1, at = 0, cex = 1.25, "Subtitle", col = '#666664')
```

`line` is for the height,
`cex` works as the size of the text,
`at` is the position (left - negative or right - positive, 0 center)

Answer (score 0):

The order actually are very simple.
You can just change the order in the data

```
df <- data.frame(Jan = 2230, Feb = 2420, Mar = 2833, Apr = 2192, May = 2332, Jun = 2577, Jul = 4363, Aug = 3747, Sep = 3176, Oct = 3988, Nov = 2144, Dec = 1896)
df = df[, c(12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)] # change the order
df <- rbind(4363, 0, df)
```

Insted of this `title = "Title"` you can use this for the title font size

```
title=("title", vlcex=0.5)
```

Comment: Hi Gutemberg, thanks for your reply. The ordering works fine, but I'm getting a Unexpected symbol error for the title part :S